# How to fix this error(convert wchar_t to BSTR)?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, and I am trying to compile this code, and get error as below,
could anyone give me a guide to fix it? thanks a lot.
i searched a lot on google, still cannot solve it

```
Error   C2664   'HRESULT IRegistrationInfo::put_Author(BSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const wchar_t [12]' to 'BSTR'    ConsoleApplication7 c:\users\hellojeff\source\repos\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7.cpp 135 1   
Warning C4603   '_WIN32_DCOM': macro is not defined or definition is different after precompiled header use ConsoleApplication7 c:\users\hellojeff\source\repos\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7.cpp 5   1   
Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "BSTR"    ConsoleApplication7 C:\Users\HelloJeff\source\repos\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7.cpp 135 28
```

seems that const wchar_ cannot be converted to 'BSTR' for this line,

```
hr = pRegInfo->put_Author(L"Author Name");
```

the full code is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/logon-trigger-example--c---,

Comment: try `hr = pRegInfo->put_Author(_bstr_t(L"Author Name"));`

Comment: Great, error disappear. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
hr = pRegInfo->put_Author(_bstr_t(L"Author Name"));
```

A `BSTR` is a different sort of string to a wide string literal. The `_bstr_t` class is a wrapper that , in this case, makes a temporary `BSTR` out of the literal in order to pass to the function.

See [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/12/erics-complete-guide-to-bstr-semantics/) for more information